# How can I compile STL C++ for Android using custom Makefile?

Tags: android, c++, stl, makefile, android-ndk

I am compiling some sources for Android using a custom Makefile, along the lines of:

```
NDKDIR := /path/to/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
NDKCC := $(NDKDIR)/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
NDKCXX := $(NDKDIR)/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
NDKFLAGS := -I/path/to/android-ndk-r10c/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/

%.o: %.cpp
    $(NDKCXX) $(NDKFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Compiling regular C++ code works fine, but anything that includes "STL" headers, such as `queue` fail with "fatal error: queue: No such file or directory".

Is there any way to make this work with the STL headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too, so I placed those three, and resolved.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D_STLP_USE_NEWALLOC
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${NDK_ROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lstdc++
```

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that the above works also when using a custom Makefile instead of the Android ndk-build system